# Pandas: Create Multiple Lists from DataFrame based on Conditions

Tags: pandas, dataframe, list, loops

Believe it or not I'm getting better at this coding thing. Sorry for (another) rudimentary question.

I'm looking to create multiple Lists from a Pandas DataFrame based on certain conditions. I want to make the contents of Column XX into a List based on criteria in Column YY.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

List1 = ['A','B','C','D]
List2 = ['AA','BB','AA','BB']

DF1 = pd.DataFrame(
{'XX': List1,
 'YY': List2})

DF1
    XX  YY
0   A   AA
1   B   BB
2   C   AA
3   D   BB
```

In practice I don't have the two lists first, just the DF. What I'm looking for is 2 Lists:

List_AA = ['A','C'] and List_BB = ['B','D']

I've tried the simple version (i.e. hard coding each one at a time which is poor, i know) but it doesn't work anyway...

```
List_AA = DF1['XX'].tolist(DF1.loc(DF1['YY']=='AA')
List_BB = DF1['XX'].tolist(DF1.loc(DF1['YY']=='BB')

or i've tried

List_AA = DF1['XX'].tolist(np.where[DF1['YY'] == 'AA')
```

...so i can't move on to the more complex version, which would be something like:

```
(psuedo code) 

List3 = DF1['YY'].unique().tolist()

for i in List3:
    List_'i' = DF['XX'].tolist(DF1.loc(DF1['YY']==i))
```

Thanks in advance. I know these are dumbish questions but I'm trying my best. Hard to learn new skills at +40yrs old :)

Kind Regards,

Devon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). Groupby creates groups according to unique values in a given column.

```
df.groupby('YY').groups
```

Output

```
{'AA': ['A', 'C'], 'BB': ['B', 'D']}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works but I don't get it. Would you mind explaining a bit what is happening here?

Comment: Oh. My bad. Added a simpler version. You can refer to the documentation for a more in-depth understanding. Groupby is similar to Pivot table in excel @Dev1602

Comment: Thank you!  I can create a Dictionary of Lists by using group y. so i can create say Dict_YY = df.groupby('YY').groups. Is this a fair interpretation?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, using list comprehension:

```
[DF1.loc[DF1['YY'].eq(y), 'XX'].to_list() for y in DF1['YY'].unique()]
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'C'], ['B', 'D']]
```